# Python: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, list, sorting

```
#Uses python3

import sys

def max_dot_product(a,b,n):


    a = a.sort(reverse=True)
    b = b.sort(reverse=True)
    res = 0

    for i in range(n):
        res += a[i]*b[i]
    return res

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = [int(x) for x in input("").split()]
    n = data[0]
    a = data[1:(n + 1)]
    b = data[(n + 1):]
    print(max_dot_product(a,b,n))
```

When I run this code, it reveals that "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sort` sorts a list **in place** and (implicitly) returns `None`. Drop the assignment of the return value and you should be OK:

```
a.sort(reverse=True)
b.sort(reverse=True)
```